# Why does iostream define an abs function, and how can I stop it?

Tags: c++, gcc

The following c++ code does not compile:

```
int main() {
  double a = abs(5.1);
  return 0;
}
```

It complains that `abs` is not defined, of course.  But the following does compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << abs(5.1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << abs(-5.1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs two 5's (not 5.1's).  This is bad for lots of reasons.  First, `abs` is such a natural and common function that I use it all the time, but the `int` part is almost never what I want returned.  Second, it's much too easy for me (or people using my code) to just write `abs` and not notice that it compiles but does the wrong thing, because I'm (they're) really good at overlooking warnings.  Third, I just plain don't understand why iostream bothers defining an `abs` function anyway.  Fourth, I *really* don't understand why it goes into the global namespace.

Is there any way I can prevent this objectionable `abs` function from going into my global namespace?

If it matters, I'm using

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.6)
```

Comment: This is probably because `<iostream>` is `#include`-ing `<stdlib.h>` behind the scenes.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. There shouldn't be an `abs` function in the global namespace when you include `<iostream>` (doesn't compile in g++ 4.6.2 and http://ideone.com/QP6cj).

Comment: @Zeta - it *does* compile and import `abs` to the global namespace using the compiler and OS that he has, I tested it to make sure. That's the current Xcode from Apple, so upgrading isn't straightforward.

Comment: Look at the output from `g++ -M test.cpp` to see if a suspect `stdlib.h` is getting pulled in for some reason.  Maybe you have an include path that causes the wrong one to get processed?

Comment: @Zeta and Brian -- I agree with both of you.  I don't actually use Xcode, but checked with the default compiler because I'd prefer for my code to work correctly as generically as possible.  But if I can't hack a workaround, maybe I should just tell my users that gcc 4.3 (or whatever) is the minimal requirement (and figure out the comparable requirements for intel, etc.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely `iostream` includes `stdlib.h` to do some of its work. This is the C version of the header which declares `abs` for `int` only in the global namespace (in C you had to use `fabs` for `double` values).

I'm not aware of any specific way to keep `abs` from being included that way but I do know that g++ 4.5 is *much* better at not having excess stuff brought in by basic includes like `iostream` and `string`.

It may also be possible to get a warning that the double is being truncated to int (EDIT: yes, use `-Wconversion` to warn).

Comment: Well, I knew about the warning, but -- as I alluded to in the question -- I'll have users extending my code, and I'm sure they'll turn off warnings, or just ignore them.  And then this pernicious little `abs` issue will slip through and give quietly incorrect results.  Ooh, this kind of thing irks me!  Anyway, thanks for pointing out the cause.

Comment: @Mike: when you say, "this kind of thing irks me", you mean it irks you that ignoring warnings leads erroneous code, right? ;-p

Comment: Well, I guess both irk me.  But human nature being what it is, I try to design for idiot-proofness.  Things like this quiet `abs` inclusion are the opposite: they're clevely hidden idiot traps.  They're so cleverly hidden that the idiot may never even know he/she was trapped.  And to top it off, this one actively prevents me from idiot-proofing!  So this irks me more.

Answer (score 5):

In C, including one standard header was *not* allowed to act like it included any other standard header. This avoided the problem you're seeing, at considerable expense in difficulty implementation.

C++ allows any standard header to include any other standard header. This makes implementation considerably easier, but can lead to exactly the sort of problem you're seeing, where including a seemingly-unrelated header has made a function visible that you didn't really want to use, instead of getting an error because the function you used isn't declared at all.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to deal with this. Although it's pretty easy to imagine `<iostream>` being independent of `<stdlib.h>`, it's much easier to see how it might need/want definitions of things like `ios_base`. It would take quite a bit of extra work to define things to prohibit the former while allowing the latter.

I should mention, however, that over time this situation does seem to be improving quite a bit. Ten years ago, it was fairly common to get virtually all standard headers from including almost any one of them. Although most still include at least a few that aren't strictly required, they're generally much closer to each defining only what it's required to.

Comment: If nothing else, you could hope that `iostream` includes `cstdlib` instead of `stdlib.h`, and that `cstdlib` either doesn't include `stdlib.h` at all, or else cleverly does so inside namespace `std`. But as you say, that's not guaranteed, and manifestly it isn't what GCC 4.2 does.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You could hope, but then so many compilers polluted the global namespace when you included the `<cwhatever>` variant, that in C++11, the restriction against doing so has been removed...

Answer (score 1):

If this is an ongoing maintenance problem, why not add a little code at the beginning of the program which specifically checks for the `abs()` problem?

```
// test if abs() is defined incorrectly, as would happen if <stdlib.h> were
// included by <iostream>.  abs() it should return a float/double, not an int
// (put suggestions here how to fix problem)
if (abs(-5.1) == 5)
{
     std::cerr << "Invalid build:  abs() defined improperly, ..." << std::endl;
     return 2;  // exit program by returning from main
}
```

That will make it a lot harder for warnings to be overlooked.

Comment: Interesting idea.  It's pretty ugly, but I think I'd actually do it -- except that much of my code is used as a library.  So it's not clear where I'd put such a test and get it actually executed -- at least, not without making this solution far uglier.

Comment: @Mike:  The obvious place would be any bit of code which is always called, like the initialization of the library.  Does the code base use `ASSERT`?  And/or have a `DEBUG` mode?  Any of these are compatible with such a test.

Comment: Nope, no such place.  It's a very modular library, and doesn't need initialization.  What's worse is that the correctness of a particular `abs` depends on whether or not statements like `using namespace std;` are used.  In that case, this test would presumably have to happen in each compilation unit -- including the user's, where applicable.