# C++11 exit() and abs() without including <cstdlib>?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please tell me why this code is compiled with C++11 standard:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  abs(-12);
  exit(1);
  return 0;
}
```

it is without error `g++ -std=++11 main.cpp`
this error `g++ main.cpp`

if you remove `#include <iostream>` then get the error on `exit()` and `abs()` when the program is compiled.
Tell me why this happens, if I don't include `<cstdlib>`? And how to do that would compile with `-std=c++11` was a warning or error?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9725509/4944425

Comment: What is exactly your question? Why removing #include<iostream> produce the error in exit() and abs() ?

Comment: I think he asks why removing `-std=c++11` produces the error.

Comment: Yes, I was interested in disabling the `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is really simple: the code compiles because under C++11 your `iostream` lib includes other libraries that have `exit()` and `abs()` defined. You won't get a warning or error for that. Why would you? After all cascade includes are supported.

However you should not depend on that since that's not a part of the standard and may break under different compiler. But I guess that as long as you stick to one compiler and one `-std` flag you're fine. Also fixing this by adding some includes should not be a big deal as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I have one question where exactly inside `<iostream>` connect these functions. I searched but could not find anything. Or need to look at the gcc files and which ones?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКуркин Obviously you have to look at the appropriate header files: `$ sudo find / -name 'iostream'`. The file has the same name as in include obviously, it's just a matter of where it is located in your OS. It may take you a while to travel through the tree of includes and macros (yes, those files include other files). My advice: don't bother. There really are better things to do. :D